# Dumping pipeline with custom class estimator, TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pickle

I'm facing a problem when I try to dump a Sci-kit learn pipeline into a pickle file.
I've defined one class per step into the pipeline.

```
def main():
   pipeline = Pipeline(
        steps=[
            ("preprocess_sales_data", PreprocessSalesData()),
            ("preprocess_article_info", PreprocessArticleInfo()),
            ("find_neighbours", CustomKMeans()),
            ("sales_regressor", ForecastPredictor())
        ]
    )

   joblib.dump(pipeline, 'pipe.joblib')


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

each of those clases extend from BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin, and/or RegressorMixin.
The class PreprocessArticleInfo has **ColumnTransformer** from sci-kit Learn and the ForecastPredictor class has inside an instance of **lightgbm.LGBMRegressor** which is trained and then use to forescast values. And CustomKmeans class has an instance of **Kmeans** of sci-kit learn that is also trained and used to transform values.
All the data is stored in pandas DataFrames.

An example of the classes

```
class CustomKMeans(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, pretrained =False, force_transformation=False, cluster_parameters = {}):
        super().__init__()
        self.pretrained = pretrained
        self.force_transformation = force_transformation
        self.cluster_parameters = cluster_parameters
        
        self.KMeans = KMeans(**self.cluster_parameters)
```

At the moment of saving the pipeline into a pickle file i got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 82, in main
    joblib.dump(pipeline, 'test_pipeline.pkl')
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 480, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 409, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 781, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 805, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 781, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 808, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 634, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)
  File "/anaconda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 496, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

I tried with pickle, joblib, cloudpickle and Dill and all of them are showing the same error.
I can't figure where the problem is coming from.

UPDATE: I ran the code in a jupyter notebook without a main function, just as a script and it worked and pickle could dump the model. I still need to fix it because i want to deploy the model.